# Can search history be seen by Apple ID?

Tags: ios, safari, apple-id, browser-history

I was searching up homework answers 3 years ago on my iPod but my cousin and I share an Apple ID that she made, and before that and before I had her Apple ID I had my Uncle's I don’t want them to know and tell my mom. Did they see my search history?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to see search history.

If Safari for iCloud is enabled all enabled devices will be able to see your search history when going into the tabs screen to see what tanks are open. NOTE: This is only recent history. I doubt that 4 years back you will be able to view it.

If you want to turn off search history go to Settings -> [your name] -> iCloud and turn Safari off.

Comment: But how do they know If it’s mine? And my iPod broke but before it broke I logged out of both then I made my new Apple ID

Comment: The name of your device will be visible and then your history. If it broke Data should be still viewable

Comment: But I only saw my tabs not other people’s tabs

Comment: @May it means that all other family members have disabled their history